# Massive Mscorlib file in nativeassemblies, can't clean up

Tags: windows-server-2003

I'm running windows server 2003 and just uninstalled Exchange 2007 as we've moved to Gmail.

After a restart, I get warnings my system drive space is low, I hit it with WinDirStat and find that my NativeAssemblies folder is a whopping 7.9 GB, with a single file (mscorlib) taking up >7gb itself (This is almost 40% of my entire drive!).

How do I remove, shrink, or otherwise clean up this unexpectedly ballooned file?  I can't find anybody that has had a similar issue.

I tried to clean up using NGen.exe, but I obviously don't have a good understanding of these files: I cannot uninstall NGen.exe for a massive list of dependencies, as well as the error "Error: The specified assembly is not installed"

I do not want to straight delete it, as my research indicates IIS uses some NativeAssemblies, and they are dependend on Mscorlib.

My winSxS folder is <150 mb (Some searches indicated this may be relevant data)

Comment: It's Server 2003.  You should reformat the server and put a modern OS on it, instead of wasting time messing around with an obsolete OS.

Comment: There is that...

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately, my boss doesn't like writing checks for anything new until the old breaks quite permanently.  And really, this is a .net issue, so the OS version shouldn't affect the actual issue much, I'd assume.

Comment: @CTB Is it possible to reformat the server and put a.... *<shudder>* fresh copy of Server 2003 on it?  That would seem like the easiest solution, unless there's a bunch of other stuff installed on it.

Comment: Aye, that's genuinely possible.  I was hoping I'd find a less time consuming solution though. It's a secondary DC/DNS server. I guess I come from a world where 10 years isn't really very old for a unit.

Comment: @CTB I don't think there is one... you can't safely delete those files, because you don't know what programs depend on them, and finding out would undoubtedly take much longer than just reinstalling.